# How to move Knockout viewmodel outside html page

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, templating

How can i move the javascript code that's using knockout outside the html file? I want to create a separate file where everything is handled (or as much as possible). Also the templating should still work. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Changes made. I have added the require.js in my Scripts folder and made an app.js and viewmodel.js file. But this still won't work. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

EDIT2: Almost there, Rumesh Eranga gave the right answer with using require.js. I only have a little problem left with my binding. 'data-bind="text: $(item.name)"' won't show the name, only '[object Object]'.

EDIT3: SOLVED!

This is the HTML file:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="Script/app.js" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script id="shoppingItemTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li><span data-bind="text: item.name"></span></li>
</script>

<div id="ActiveShoppingList">
<h2>Shopping items</h2>
<div id="ActiveList">
    <ul data-bind="template: {name:'shoppingItemTemplate', foreach: items, as:'item'}"></ul>
    <button data-bind="click:addItem">Add item</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is my Script/app.js:

```
require(['knockout-3.2.0', 'viewmodel'], function(ko, viewmodel) {
ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel);
});
```

And here is my Script/viewmodel.js:

```
define(['knockout-3.2.0'], function(ko) {
return function viewmodel (){
    this.items = ko.observableArray([new item("item1"), new item("item2")]);
    this.addItem = function()
        {
            this.items.push(new item("new item"));
        };
};

function item(name)
{
    return { name: ko.observable(name) };
}
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you load the external HTML partial via ajax, and upon loading that HTML file, just applyBindings at that time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) With RequireJs.

Good article on Require and knockout can be found [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html).

Quoting from the site.

> HTML
>
> ```
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <script type="text/javascript" data-main="scripts/init.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
>         <p>First name capitalized: <strong data-bind="text: firstNameCaps"></strong></p>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> scope/init.js
>
> ```
> require(['knockout-x.y.z', 'appViewModel', 'domReady!'], function(ko, appViewModel) {
>     ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
> });
> ```
>
> scripts/appViewModel.js
>
> ```
> // Main viewmodel class
> define(['knockout-x.y.z'], function(ko) {
>     return function appViewModel() {
>         this.firstName = ko.observable('Bert');
>         this.firstNameCaps = ko.pureComputed(function() {
>             return this.firstName().toUpperCase();
>         }, this);
>     };
> });
> ```

According to the code snippet given above you can see that you can make your view model code separate from the html and even can be modularize which is much helpful.

Comment: Any errors on the console? My guess is  <li>${$data.name}</li> is wrong. Try changing that to  <li>$data.name</li>

Comment: Changed the foreach a little bit to make it more easy: "... foreach: items, as:'item'}".

Also changed this:
<li><span data-bind="text: $(item.name)"></span></li>

Now i can add items and i see them adding up... But i still don't see their names i can only see '[object Object]'. Must be something wrong with my text: $(item.name) but i can't find it... Tried a lot and i have no console errors... Thanks for the help i'm almost there! :D

Comment: I think you don't have to use '$' sign there. Try <span data-bind="text: item.name"></span> . This should work.

Comment: Rumesh Eranga strikes again! Thanks! :)